# PDO prepared statement not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

The prepared query returns the following resultset, when `$this->show` is set to `saved-by-the-bell`:

```
season
------
1
2
3
4
```

When I execute the following code:

```
$seasons = array( );

$query = $db->prepare(
  "SELECT `season` " .
  "FROM `tv` " .
  "WHERE `show_url` = ':show' " . 
  "GROUP BY `season` " .
  "ORDER BY `season` ASC;"
);

$query->bindParam( ':show', $this->show );
$query->execute( );
$query->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

while( $row = $query->fetch( ) )
{
  $season = new stdClass;
  $season->number = $row->season;
  $season->title = "Season {$row->season}";
  $season->url = $row->season;

  $seasons[] = $season;
}

return $seasons;
```

**`$seasons` is an empty array, why?**

$db is an instantiated object that extends PDO.

I've tried all kinds of debugging methods, but when I echo the rowCount, it says 0.  I'm still new to PDO, but I can't seem to see what's wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you've checked to see if the SQL returns anything directly from MySQL?

Comment: not your problem but, fyi - in php strings can span multiple lines.

Comment: But then, I think they contain line breaks, and for some reason I am anal and do not want my strings to have these unnecessary characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahhh, I figured it out.  I'll leave my stupidity up here, in case anyone else happens across this.

Apparently, when using prepared statements, you don't need to wrap your parameters in quotes in the SQL code.

So, the prepare statement should look like this:

```
$query = $db->prepare(
  "SELECT `season` " .
  "FROM `tv` " .
  "WHERE `show_url` = :show " . 
  "GROUP BY `season` " .
  "ORDER BY `season` ASC;"
);
```

Comment: The way to remember is that these are *bind variables* and not simply string substitutions.